# Anybody got a C# function that maps the SQL datatype of a column to its CLR equivalent?

Tags: c#, types

I'm sitting down to write a massive switch() statement to turn SQL datatypes into CLR datatypes in order to generate classes from MSSQL stored procedures. I'm using [this chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx) as a reference. Before I get too far into what will probably take all day and be a huge pain to fully test, I'd like to call out to the SO community to see if anyone else has already written or found something in C# to accomplish this seemingly common and assuredly tedious task.

Comment: I have in the past implemented a very similar system, but not for C#. I've been meaning to build something like this, but I just haven't got around to it yet. Is your implementation going to be closed or might it be open-sourced? Because I'm sure I and others would be very interested in an open source implementation of just what you describe.

Comment: This is for commercial development.

Comment: This may not have been available in 2009, but System.Web may have what is required here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28561947/4228193 . `try { return Convert.ChangeType(value_to_convert, Parameter.ConvertDbTypeToTypeCode(SqlMetaData_instance.DbT‌​ype); }` also available: ConvertTypeCodeToDbType (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.converttypecodetodbtype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This is the one we use. You may want to tweak it (e.g. nullable/non-nullable types etc.) but it should save you most of the typing.

```
public static Type GetClrType(SqlDbType sqlType)
{
    switch (sqlType)
    {
        case SqlDbType.BigInt:
            return typeof(long?);

        case SqlDbType.Binary:
        case SqlDbType.Image:
        case SqlDbType.Timestamp:
        case SqlDbType.VarBinary:
            return typeof(byte[]);

        case SqlDbType.Bit:
            return typeof(bool?);

        case SqlDbType.Char:
        case SqlDbType.NChar:
        case SqlDbType.NText:
        case SqlDbType.NVarChar:
        case SqlDbType.Text:
        case SqlDbType.VarChar:
        case SqlDbType.Xml:
            return typeof(string);

        case SqlDbType.DateTime:
        case SqlDbType.SmallDateTime:
        case SqlDbType.Date:
        case SqlDbType.Time:
        case SqlDbType.DateTime2:
            return typeof(DateTime?);

        case SqlDbType.Decimal:
        case SqlDbType.Money:
        case SqlDbType.SmallMoney:
            return typeof(decimal?);

        case SqlDbType.Float:
            return typeof(double?);

        case SqlDbType.Int:
            return typeof(int?);

        case SqlDbType.Real:
            return typeof(float?);

        case SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier:
            return typeof(Guid?);

        case SqlDbType.SmallInt:
            return typeof(short?);

        case SqlDbType.TinyInt:
            return typeof(byte?);

        case SqlDbType.Variant:
        case SqlDbType.Udt:
            return typeof(object);

        case SqlDbType.Structured:
            return typeof(DataTable);

        case SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset:
            return typeof(DateTimeOffset?);

        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("sqlType");
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you make use of this method?

Comment: @user457104 - Erm... you call it like any other method.

Comment: No, I mean, I don't understand what you use it for. Do you use the return value to dynamically create the type? Do you use it to compare it to something else? In code, in what situation would I want to convert from SqlDbType to Type? I'm sure there's a good use for it, but I can't think of it. Hence, I'm asking.

Comment: @user457104 - We use it in our tool that generates .NET wrapper classes for our stored procedures. It determines the SQL parameter types and generates a wrapper with the corresponding CLR type using this function. It's not that common a use case really.

Comment: Where is HierarchyId ?

Comment: I get an error: "Static types cannot be used as parameters".

Comment: Why  returning nullable CLR types ?

Comment: @activebiz nullable columns... You could test for column nullability as well if you wanted to really jazz it up...

Answer (score 9):

```
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DbVsCSharpTypes]    Script Date: 03/20/2010 03:07:56 ******/
    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DbVsCSharpTypes]') 
    AND type in (N'U'))
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[DbVsCSharpTypes]
    GO

    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DbVsCSharpTypes]    Script Date: 03/20/2010 03:07:56 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DbVsCSharpTypes](
        [DbVsCSharpTypesId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Sql2008DataType] [varchar](200) NULL,
        [CSharpDataType] [varchar](200) NULL,
        [CLRDataType] [varchar](200) NULL,
        [CLRDataTypeSqlServer] [varchar](2000) NULL,

     CONSTRAINT [PK_DbVsCSharpTypes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [DbVsCSharpTypesId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO


    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    GO

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DbVsCSharpTypes] ON;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[DbVsCSharpTypes]([DbVsCSharpTypesId], [Sql2008DataType], [CSharpDataType], [CLRDataType], [CLRDataTypeSqlServer])
    SELECT 1, N'bigint', N'long', N'Int64, Nullable<Int64>', N'SqlInt64' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, N'binary', N'byte[]', N'Byte[]', N'SqlBytes, SqlBinary' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, N'bit', N'bool', N'Boolean, Nullable<Boolean>', N'SqlBoolean' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, N'char', N'char', NULL, NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, N'cursor', NULL, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, N'date', N'DateTime', N'DateTime, Nullable<DateTime>', N'SqlDateTime' UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, N'datetime', N'DateTime', N'DateTime, Nullable<DateTime>', N'SqlDateTime' UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, N'datetime2', N'DateTime', N'DateTime, Nullable<DateTime>', N'SqlDateTime' UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, N'DATETIMEOFFSET', N'DateTimeOffset', N'DateTimeOffset', N'DateTimeOffset, Nullable<DateTimeOffset>' UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, N'decimal', N'decimal', N'Decimal, Nullable<Decimal>', N'SqlDecimal' UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, N'float', N'double', N'Double, Nullable<Double>', N'SqlDouble' UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, N'geography', NULL, NULL, N'SqlGeography is defined in Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll, which is installed with SQL Server and can be downloaded from the SQL Server 2008 feature pack.' UNION ALL
    SELECT 13, N'geometry', NULL, NULL, N'SqlGeometry is defined in Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll, which is installed with SQL Server and can be downloaded from the SQL Server 2008 feature pack.' UNION ALL
    SELECT 14, N'hierarchyid', NULL, NULL, N'SqlHierarchyId is defined in Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll, which is installed with SQL Server and can be downloaded from the SQL Server 2008 feature pack.' UNION ALL
    SELECT 15, N'image', NULL, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT 16, N'int', N'int', N'Int32, Nullable<Int32>', N'SqlInt32' UNION ALL
    SELECT 17, N'money', N'decimal', N'Decimal, Nullable<Decimal>', N'SqlMoney' UNION ALL
    SELECT 18, N'nchar', N'string', N'String, Char[]', N'SqlChars, SqlString' UNION ALL
    SELECT 19, N'ntext', NULL, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT 20, N'numeric', N'decimal', N'Decimal, Nullable<Decimal>', N'SqlDecimal' UNION ALL
    SELECT 21, N'nvarchar', N'string', N'String, Char[]', N'SqlChars, SqlStrinG SQLChars is a better match for data transfer and access, and SQLString is a better match for performing String operations.' UNION ALL
    SELECT 22, N'nvarchar(1), nchar(1)', N'string', N'Char, String, Char[], Nullable<char>', N'SqlChars, SqlString' UNION ALL
    SELECT 23, N'real', N'single', N'Single, Nullable<Single>', N'SqlSingle' UNION ALL
    SELECT 24, N'rowversion', N'byte[]', N'Byte[]', NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT 25, N'smallint', N'smallint', N'Int16, Nullable<Int16>', N'SqlInt16' UNION ALL
    SELECT 26, N'smallmoney', N'decimal', N'Decimal, Nullable<Decimal>', N'SqlMoney' UNION ALL
    SELECT 27, N'sql_variant', N'object', N'Object', NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT 28, N'table', NULL, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT 29, N'text', N'string', NULL, NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT 30, N'time', N'TimeSpan', N'TimeSpan, Nullable<TimeSpan>', N'TimeSpan' UNION ALL
    SELECT 31, N'timestamp', NULL, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT 32, N'tinyint', N'byte', N'Byte, Nullable<Byte>', N'SqlByte' UNION ALL
    SELECT 33, N'uniqueidentifier', N'Guid', N'Guid, Nullable<Guid>', N'SqlGuidUser-defined type(UDT)The same class that is bound to the user-defined type in the same assembly or a dependent assembly.' UNION ALL
    SELECT 34, N'varbinary ', N'byte[]', N'Byte[]', N'SqlBytes, SqlBinary' UNION ALL
    SELECT 35, N'varbinary(1), binary(1)', N'byte', N'byte, Byte[], Nullable<byte>', N'SqlBytes, SqlBinary' UNION ALL
    SELECT 36, N'varchar', NULL, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT 37, N'xml', NULL, NULL, N'SqlXml'
    COMMIT;
    RAISERROR (N'[dbo].[DbVsCSharpTypes]: Insert Batch: 1.....Done!', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
    GO

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DbVsCSharpTypes] OFF;
```

Comment: The only way to handle data is to be able  to handle the metadata. In order to be able to handle the metadata one should be able use its data. In order to be able to use its data it must be described properly ...

Comment: I can't believe no one has spotted this in the last 4.5 years, but a SQL bigint isn't equivalent to a C# short.. I think you meant long (aka Int64)!

Comment: Is there a reason varchar has NULL data types?

Comment: Good point. The only reason I could think of is just the fact that the code was in "work in progress status" - that is without testing now I changed it to NOT NULL by intuition ... unless anyone justifies why it should not be done ...

Comment: Good table but one column is missing MSSQL system_type_id

Answer (score 6):

Here's a revision that accepts nullable.

```
    public static Type GetClrType(SqlDbType sqlType, bool isNullable)
    {
        switch (sqlType)
        {
            case SqlDbType.BigInt:
                return isNullable ? typeof(long?) : typeof(long);

            case SqlDbType.Binary:
            case SqlDbType.Image:
            case SqlDbType.Timestamp:
            case SqlDbType.VarBinary:
                return typeof(byte[]);

            case SqlDbType.Bit:
                return isNullable ? typeof(bool?) : typeof(bool);

            case SqlDbType.Char:
            case SqlDbType.NChar:
            case SqlDbType.NText:
            case SqlDbType.NVarChar:
            case SqlDbType.Text:
            case SqlDbType.VarChar:
            case SqlDbType.Xml:
                return typeof(string);

            case SqlDbType.DateTime:
            case SqlDbType.SmallDateTime:
            case SqlDbType.Date:
            case SqlDbType.Time:
            case SqlDbType.DateTime2:
                return isNullable ? typeof(DateTime?) : typeof(DateTime);

            case SqlDbType.Decimal:
            case SqlDbType.Money:
            case SqlDbType.SmallMoney:
                return isNullable ? typeof(decimal?) : typeof(decimal);

            case SqlDbType.Float:
                return isNullable ? typeof(double?) : typeof(double);

            case SqlDbType.Int:
                return isNullable ? typeof(int?) : typeof(int);

            case SqlDbType.Real:
                return isNullable ? typeof(float?) : typeof(float);

            case SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier:
                return isNullable ? typeof(Guid?) : typeof(Guid);

            case SqlDbType.SmallInt:
                return isNullable ? typeof(short?) : typeof(short);

            case SqlDbType.TinyInt:
                return isNullable ? typeof(byte?) : typeof(byte);

            case SqlDbType.Variant:
            case SqlDbType.Udt:
                return typeof(object);

            case SqlDbType.Structured:
                return typeof(DataTable);

            case SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset:
                return isNullable ? typeof(DateTimeOffset?) : typeof(DateTimeOffset);

            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("sqlType");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    internal Type type(SqlDbType sqltype)
    {
        Type resulttype = null;
        Dictionary<SqlDbType, Type> Types = new Dictionary<SqlDbType, Type>();
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.BigInt, typeof(Int64));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.Binary, typeof(Byte[]));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.Bit, typeof(Boolean));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.Char, typeof(String));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.Date, typeof(DateTime));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.DateTime, typeof(DateTime));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.DateTime2, typeof(DateTime));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset, typeof(DateTimeOffset));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.Decimal, typeof(Decimal));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.Float, typeof(Double));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.Image, typeof(Byte[]));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.Int, typeof(Int32));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.Money, typeof(Decimal));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.NChar, typeof(String));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.NText, typeof(String));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.NVarChar, typeof(String));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.Real, typeof(Single));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.SmallDateTime, typeof(DateTime));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.SmallInt, typeof(Int16));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.SmallMoney, typeof(Decimal));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.Text, typeof(String));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.Time, typeof(TimeSpan));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.Timestamp, typeof(Byte[]));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.TinyInt, typeof(Byte));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, typeof(Guid));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.VarBinary, typeof(Byte[]));
        Types.Add(SqlDbType.VarChar, typeof(String));
        Types.TryGetValue(sqltype, out resulttype);
        return resulttype;
    }

    internal SqlDbType type(Type systype)
    {
        SqlDbType resulttype = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        Dictionary<Type, SqlDbType> Types = new Dictionary<Type, SqlDbType>();
        Types.Add(typeof(Boolean), SqlDbType.Bit);
        Types.Add(typeof(String), SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        Types.Add(typeof(DateTime), SqlDbType.DateTime);
        Types.Add(typeof(Int16), SqlDbType.Int);
        Types.Add(typeof(Int32), SqlDbType.Int);
        Types.Add(typeof(Int64), SqlDbType.Int);
        Types.Add(typeof(Decimal), SqlDbType.Float);
        Types.Add(typeof(Double), SqlDbType.Float);
        Types.TryGetValue(systype, out resulttype);
        return resulttype;
    }
```

Comment: Does anyone know if the `Dictionary.TryGetValue()` this approach shown here is any faster or slower than the `switch...case` appoach shown elsewhere in this thread?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a function.I think you may be looking for

```
dt.Columns[i].DataType.UnderlyingSystemType
```

*dt - dataTable*

This will return the CLR type for corresponding column.
Hope this helps and BTW this is my first answer on stack **overflow**

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't directly answer the question as asked, but it does answer a common related one. Once you have an `IDataReader` you can call [`IDataRecord.GetFieldType(int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getfieldtype.aspx) to "[get] the `Type` information corresponding to the type of `Object` that would be returned from `GetValue`."

Comment: If you've got an object that was read from a field, you can also use the SqlMetaData.InferFromValue (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlmetadata.inferfromvalue.aspx)method to work out it's type.

Answer (score 3):

I include this extension (you could easily exchange the string key in the dictionary for SqlDbType as Greg has implemented - or even support both) in my model and expose a property that converts the CLR Type:

```
    namespace X.Domain.Model
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        public class StoredProcedureParameter : DomainObject
        {
            public StoredProcedureParameter() { }

            public string StoredProcedure { get; set; }

            public string ProcedureSchema { get; set; }

            public string ProcedureName { get; set; }

            public string ParameterName { get; set; }

            public string ParameterOrder { get; set; }

            public string ParameterMode { get; set; }

            public string SqlDataType { get; set; }

            public Type DataType { get { return this.SqlDataType.ToClrType(); } }
        }

        static class StoredProcedureParameterExtensions
        {
            private static Dictionary<string, Type> Mappings;
            public static StoredProcedureParameterExtensions()
            {
                Mappings = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
                Mappings.Add("bigint", typeof(Int64));
                Mappings.Add("binary", typeof(Byte[]));
                Mappings.Add("bit", typeof(Boolean));
                Mappings.Add("char", typeof(String));
                Mappings.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
                Mappings.Add("datetime", typeof(DateTime));
                Mappings.Add("datetime2", typeof(DateTime));
                Mappings.Add("datetimeoffset", typeof(DateTimeOffset));
                Mappings.Add("decimal", typeof(Decimal));
                Mappings.Add("float", typeof(Double));
                Mappings.Add("image", typeof(Byte[]));
                Mappings.Add("int", typeof(Int32));
                Mappings.Add("money", typeof(Decimal));
                Mappings.Add("nchar", typeof(String));
                Mappings.Add("ntext", typeof(String));
                Mappings.Add("numeric", typeof(Decimal));
                Mappings.Add("nvarchar", typeof(String));
                Mappings.Add("real", typeof(Single));
                Mappings.Add("rowversion", typeof(Byte[]));
                Mappings.Add("smalldatetime", typeof(DateTime));
                Mappings.Add("smallint", typeof(Int16));
                Mappings.Add("smallmoney", typeof(Decimal));
                Mappings.Add("text", typeof(String));
                Mappings.Add("time", typeof(TimeSpan));
                Mappings.Add("timestamp", typeof(Byte[]));
                Mappings.Add("tinyint", typeof(Byte));
                Mappings.Add("uniqueidentifier", typeof(Guid));
                Mappings.Add("varbinary", typeof(Byte[]));
                Mappings.Add("varchar", typeof(String));

            }

            public static Type ToClrType(this string sqlType)
            {
                Type datatype = null;
                if (Mappings.TryGetValue(sqlType, out datatype))
                    return datatype;
                throw new TypeLoadException(string.Format("Can not load CLR Type from {0}", sqlType));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Wizardby](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby/). However, it maps from so-called "native" data types to `DbType`, which are then trivial to convert to CLR types. If this fits, you'll need an appropriate `IDbTypeMapper` - either `SqlServer2000TypeMapper` or `SqlServer2005TypeMapper`.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Data;
namespace System.CoreEssentials
{
    public static class SqlTypesExtensions
    {

        public static Type SqlToType(this string pSqlType)
        {
            switch (pSqlType)
            {
                case "bigint":
                case "real":
                    return typeof(long);
                case "numeric":
                    return typeof(decimal);
                case "bit":
                    return typeof(bool);

                case "smallint":
                    return typeof(short);

                case "decimal":
                case "smallmoney":
                case "money":
                    return typeof(decimal);

                case "int":
                    return typeof(int);

                case "tinyint":
                    return typeof(byte);

                case "float":
                    return typeof(float);

                case "date":
                case "datetime2":
                case "smalldatetime":
                case "datetime":
                case "time":
                    return typeof(DateTime);

                case "datetimeoffset":
                    return typeof(DateTimeOffset);

                case "char":
                case "varchar":
                case "text":
                case "nchar":
                case "nvarchar":
                case "ntext":
                    return typeof(string);


                case "binary":
                case "varbinary":
                case "image":
                    return typeof(byte[]);

                case "uniqueidentifier":
                    return typeof(Guid);

                default:
                    return typeof(string);

            }

        }

        public static DbType ToDbType(this Type pType)
        {
            switch (pType.Name.ToLower())
            {
                case "byte":
                    return DbType.Byte;
                case "sbyte":
                    return DbType.SByte;
                case "short":
                case "int16":
                    return DbType.Int16;
                case "uint16":
                    return DbType.UInt16;
                case "int32":
                    return DbType.Int32;
                case "uint32":
                    return DbType.UInt32;
                case "int64":
                    return DbType.Int64;
                case "uint64":
                    return DbType.UInt64;
                case "single":
                    return DbType.Single;
                case "double":
                    return DbType.Double;
                case "decimal":
                    return DbType.Decimal;
                case "bool":
                case "boolean":
                    return DbType.Boolean;
                case "string":
                    return DbType.String;
                case "char":
                    return DbType.StringFixedLength;
                case "Guid":
                    return DbType.Guid;
                case "DateTime":
                    return DbType.DateTime;
                case "DateTimeOffset":
                    return DbType.DateTimeOffset;
                case "byte[]":
                    return DbType.Binary;
                case "byte?":
                    return DbType.Byte;
                case "sbyte?":
                    return DbType.SByte;
                case "short?":
                    return DbType.Int16;
                case "ushort?":
                    return DbType.UInt16;
                case "int?":
                    return DbType.Int32;
                case "uint?":
                    return DbType.UInt32;
                case "long?":
                    return DbType.Int64;
                case "ulong?":
                    return DbType.UInt64;
                case "float?":
                    return DbType.Single;
                case "double?":
                    return DbType.Double;
                case "decimal?":
                    return DbType.Decimal;
                case "bool?":
                    return DbType.Boolean;
                case "char?":
                    return DbType.StringFixedLength;
                case "Guid?":
                    return DbType.Guid;
                case "DateTime?":
                    return DbType.DateTime;
                case "DateTimeOffset?":
                    return DbType.DateTimeOffset;
                default:
                    return DbType.String;
            }

        }

        public static DbType SqlToDbType(this string pSqlType)
        {
            return pSqlType.SqlToType().ToDbType();
        }

        public static object GetDefault(this Type type)
        {
            if (type.IsValueType)
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no built in for that, but you can use VS to generate classes for your tables and then try to edit them

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a typed dataset and have the VS designer do the mapping for you? Unless the project has to adapt at runtime to different schemas, then you should use code generation techniques to create your classes, wether the built-in designers (ie. typed datasets) or custom ones (schema->XML->XSLT->.cs).

Comment: It does have to adapt to different schemas. I'm writing a generator that takes in an SP name and gens a C# class from the input and output parameters using SQL-DMO (SQL 2000)

Comment: That is also a valid approach. Greg already gave a good answer. Normally I'd recommend also considering using Stream oriented types for the large types (n/varchar/varbinary(max) and xml) but you say you're on SQL2K so it doesn't apply).

Answer (score 0):

Normally I just use the Value property to convert a SqlType to a native .NET type. This does the job most of the time. If I have a corner case, I'll just write a quick helper function.

```
int i = dataReader.GetSqlInt32(0).Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you're discussing writing a switch statement, but here's an alternate for Sql Server (similar concepts work for other DBs)

Consider using SysObjects to retrieve the full data types and generate your class:

```
declare @ProcName varchar(255)
select @ProcName='Table, View, or Proc'
SELECT --DISTINCT 
    b.name 
    , c.name Type
    , b.xtype
    , b.length 
    , b.isoutparam
FROM 
    sysObjects a 
INNER JOIN sysCOLUMNs b ON a.id=b.id 
INNER JOIN systypes c ON b.xtype=c.xtype  
WHERE 
    a.name=@ProcName
order by b.colorder
```

Now you're just enumerating a DataTable instead of the longer statement.